# How To Access Angular Material Colors In Components?

Tags: angular, angular-material

In angular material, we can pass colors to angular material components as attribute, for example

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary">Example</button>
```

I'm using multiple angular material themes, which changes dynamically.

**Required Behaviour:**
 Changing color of my custom components dynamically with theme change.

I want something like this:

```
<app-footer color="primary"></app-footer>
```

How to get color in my custom component?

**What I tried**

I had a input property in my component

```
@Input() color;
```

and tried to pass color in component

```
<app-footer color="primary"></app-footer>
```

But it didn't worked for me.
How to achieve this?

**==UPDATE==**

**Explanation:** Below lines of code are from button.ts file of angular material from its github repository

```
/**
 * Material design button.
 */
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: `button[mat-button], button[mat-raised-button], button[mat-icon-button],
             button[mat-fab], button[mat-mini-fab], button[mat-stroked-button],
             button[mat-flat-button]`,
  exportAs: 'matButton',
  host: {
    '[attr.disabled]': 'disabled || null',
    '[class._mat-animation-noopable]': '_animationMode === "NoopAnimations"',
  },
  templateUrl: 'button.html',
  styleUrls: ['button.css'],
  inputs: ['disabled', 'disableRipple', 'color'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
```

Link to file: [Button.ts](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/button/button.ts) 

Here you can see, it takes color as input. Similarly, I have also taken color as input in my footer component. Now with `<app-footer color="primary"></app-footer>` I got *primary* string as input in my footer component.
  How to get color hex from this to set background color of my footer component. Please note, primary color changes dynamically with theme change, therefore, I cannot hard-code color.

Comment: In what way didn't it work? Did you get an error in the console?

Comment: @ShamPooSham **updated** I got "primary" as string in component. I want to get color code from it. How to get that?

Comment: I think, angular material team did it in [_button_theme.scss file](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/button/_button-theme.scss). But still, I'm unable to achieve it in my footer component. Could you please explain me what they did in this file? (I'm new to scss)

Comment: If you write `<app-footer [color]="color"></app-footer>` (notice the `[` brackets `]`), it will evaluate the expression instead of just using the string you give to it.

Comment: @ShamPooSham Thanks for your reply, but `primary` is not a variable. Please note,  `primary` and `accent` are part of angular material themes, and these are not variables, so we cannot access their values using square braces `[ ]`.

Comment: Do you want the whole `app-footer` to become of that color or do you want some elements in the `app-footer` component to get that color?

Comment: @ShamPooSham background color of whole app-footer component.

Comment: You'll want to set the `class` attribute of `app-footer` to `mat-primary` in that case. You can do this inside the component code by using `HostBinding`. Then you have to defined in css how that class should be interpreted.

Comment: @ShamPooSham I tried giving `mat-primary` class to footer component but it didn't worked. Can you please elaborate what you are suggesting? BTW, please look into material.angular.io website. see how its footer color change with theme change. Link to its [github repo](https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/tree/master/src/app/shared/footer). I want something like this.

Comment: Adding the class is the first step, defining the css is the second step. I recommend using scss as in the example you linked. I'm sorry, but I don't have time to help you more right now

Comment: @ShamPooSham Thanks for your help. I have found its solution which I have posted below. Please check.

Comment: Looks good, great job!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found its solution. I'm posting it here so that if someone else requires similar behavior in their angular app, they can get it, in the following way.

I created a mixin for footer

```
 @mixin footer-theme($theme) {
        $primary: map-get($theme, primary);
        $accent: map-get($theme, accent);
        $warn: map-get($theme, warn);
        $background: map-get($theme, background);
        $foreground: map-get($theme, foreground);

        app-footer {
          .footer-primary {
              background-color: mat-color($primary);
          }
         .footer-accent {
              background-color: mat-color($accent);
          }
        }
      }
```

*`app-footer` is a component selector and `.footer-*` is a class of footer component to whom I want to apply the primary/accent background color.*

In the footer component, `color` is an [input](https://angular.io/api/core/Input). We need to pass color value while embedding the footer component in the following way.
 
*For the primary background color:*

```
<app-footer color="primary"></app-footer>
```

*For the accent background color:*

```
<app-footer color="accent"></app-footer>
```

In the footer HTML file:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'footer-primary': color === 'primary', 'footer-accent': color === 'accent'}">
      /*footer code here...*/
</div>
```

Then I included footer mixin in ***app_theme.scss*** file which has multiple themes

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@import './app/shared/footer/footer-theme';

@include mat-core();


$primary1: mat-palette($mat-teal, 500);
$accent1:  mat-palette($mat-green, A200, A100, A400);

$warn1:    mat-palette($mat-red);

$theme1: mat-light-theme($primary1, $accent1, $warn1);

@include angular-material-theme($theme1);
@include footer-theme($theme1);

// SECOND THEME
$primary2: mat-palette($mat-indigo, 500);

$accent2:  mat-palette($mat-blue, A200, A100, A400);

$warn2:    mat-palette($mat-red);

$theme2: mat-light-theme($primary2, $accent2, $warn2);

.second-theme {
    @include angular-material-theme($theme2);
    @include footer-theme($theme2);
}
```

In ***app.component.html***

```
<div [ngClass]="{'second-theme' : isSecondTheme}">
    <div class="mat-app-background">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here `isSecondTheme` is a boolean, when `true` second theme is applied, otherwise default theme. Just change boolean at runtime.

You can modify it to have more than two themes.

Comment: Though the method which worked for me is not the same what I described in question, but output is same what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

A little bit late but maybe somebody else can use it.
Here's how I did it. i needed the warn color so I could use it on one of my own elements.

Html:

```
 //This is a dummy element, invisible to the user.
 <mat-icon color="warn" [style.display]="'none'" #warnIconButton>home</mat-icon>
```

Ts:

```
 @ViewChild('warnIconButton') _warnIconButton: MatButton
 _warnColor:string = 'myFallbackColor'

 ngAfterViewInit() {
   const warnNativeElement = this._warnIconButton._elementRef?.nativeElement
   this._warnColor = getComputedStyle(warnNativeElement)?.color
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Angular Material Palette is a SASS map. It is like Map object in Javascript. So you can achieve getting colors from material by generating classes or even CSS variables.

```
@use '../palette';

@mixin generateColors($prefix, $palette) {
  $colors-map: ();

  @each $key, $value in $palette {
    @if $key !=contrast {
      .app-#{$prefix}-#{$key} {
        color: map-get($palette, $key);
      }

    $map: ();
    $map: map-merge($map, ($key: $value));
    $colors-map: map-merge($colors-map, $map);
    }
  }

  :root {
    @each $key, $value in $colors-map {
      --app-#{$prefix}-#{$key}: #{$value};
    }
  }
}

@mixin generate-material-classes {
   @include generateColors(primary, $youtube-primary);
   @include generateColors(accent, $youtube-accent);
   @include generateColors(warning, $youtube-warning);
}
```

In your styles.scss:

```
import './generate-css-classes';
@include generate-material-classes();
```

This would generate CSS classes and CSS variables like below:

[image]

Then use like classes. For example,

```
 <h1 class="app-primary-60 title"> Product title </h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually set the `[color]` property on the Angular Material component.

E.g.

```
color: string = 'primary'
```

Html:

```
<button [color]="color">My Button</button>
```

I've created a minimal example for your [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-9me1fa).

Comment: I want this same behavior with my custom components. For example: footer component. How I could pass primary/accent color of angular material to my custom component. Angular material primary/accent colors automatically changes when theme is changed.

Answer (score 0):

@Vugar Abdullayev's answer was exactly what I wanted. The thing I changed was to consider the disabled case for a button for example, because in that case, I wouldn't want to override the default disabled style, so I did it like this:

```
.app-#{$prefix}-#{$key}:not(:disabled) {
   color: map-get($palette, $key);
 }
```

what I added is the `:not(:disabled)` part.

I'm sharing this just in case anyone has that same situation and doesn't want to override the disabled case.