# Apply css style to mat-snackbar in angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript, components

I'm wondering why I've been stuck with this all afternoon, and I find it embarrassing that something so trivial is so hard to do in angular material.

I'm trying to apply a custom style to a snackbar once a button is clicked, this is my code :

```
this.errormessagecard.open(error.error.message,'Esci', {panelClass : 'error-snackbar'});
```

I've literally tried everything:

**In my component.css**

```
.error-snackbar{
  background-color: red!important;
}
```

```
error-snackbar{
  background-color: red!important;
}
```

```
::ng-deep .error-snackbar{
  background-color: red!important;
```

And the same thing in my **styles.css**

What I get is always the same result, which is this:

[Snackbar result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I68nR.png)

Nothing change, why??

Comment: Angular material inherints color by the theme you're using, those styles won't change the color.

Comment: Ok, what if i need to change it?

Comment: But i still need angular's theme on other components

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58593902/how-to-access-angular-material-colors-in-components

Check at this post

Comment: Man, i need to change only the Snackbar's background, the ViewEncapsulation : none will affect all the correct style given from angular material

Comment: Got it, check at this then: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47569076/10138953 in this case only the SnackBar is affected.

Comment: This man is using a .scss file, i'm using css.
I had seen this post before, but none of the given solutions work for me